# FullCalendar + VUE: No available FullCalendar view plugins

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar

**FullCalendar 4.4.2 + VUE**

Hello! I'm trying to run the FullCalendar plugin but it doesn't want to work. Before that, I ran the same assembly on another server and everything worked fine! Here is my connection code.
I am using the FullCalendar 4.4.2 plugin

Please tell me what could be the problem with the plugin error. Why doesn't he want to launch? Thanks in advance for any help!

ERROR: No available FullCalendar view plugins

```
<template>
    <div class="calendar-view">
        <app-overlay-loader v-if="preloader"/>
        <FullCalendar v-else :options="calendarOptions"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/vue";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction";

export default {
    name: "Calendar",
    components: {
        FullCalendar
    },
    props: {
        options: {
            type: Object
        },
        preloader: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            initOptions: {
                plugins: [dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
                headerToolbar: {
                    left: 'title',
                    center: 'prev today next',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay',
                },
                initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
                selectable: true,
                views: {
                    dayGridMonth: {
                        titleFormat: {month: 'long', year: 'numeric'}
                    },
                    timeGridWeek: {
                        titleFormat: {month: 'long', year: 'numeric'},
                        weekNumbers: true
                    },
                    timeGridDay: {
                        titleFormat: {day: 'numeric', month: 'long', year: 'numeric'},
                    }
                },
            }
        }
    },
    computed: {
        calendarOptions() {
            return {
                ...this.initOptions,
                slotLabelFormat: this.slotLabel
                , ...this.options
            }
        },
        slotLabel() {
            if (this.$store.state.settings.timeFormat === 12) return undefined;
            return {
                'hour12': false,
                'hour': '2-digit',
                'minute': '2-digit'
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

ERROR

```
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "Error: No available FullCalendar view plugins."

found in

---> <FullCalendar>
       <Calendar> at resources/js/core/components/calendar/Calendar.vue
         <ActivityCalendar> at resources/js/crm/Component/Views/Activities/Calendar/ActivityCalendar.vue
           <CalendarView> at resources/js/crm/Component/Views/Activities/CalendarView.vue
             <Root>
```

Calendar won't load. Please help me solve the problem.
Thank!

Comment: If the exact same code worked in another environment then probably there's some difference in the environment. Maybe the necessary files are not available or something. It's hard to know just from the code alone, since you stated the code is known to work correctly elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a "type" attribute when you customize Views，eg:

```
 views: {
                dayGridMonth: {
                    type: 'dayGridMonth',
                    titleFormat: {month: 'long', year: 'numeric'}
                },
                timeGridWeek: {
                    type: 'timeGridWeek',
                    titleFormat: {month: 'long', year: 'numeric'},
                    weekNumbers: true
                },
                timeGridDay: {
                    type: 'timeGridDay',
                    titleFormat: {day: 'numeric', month: 'long', year: 'numeric'},
                }
            },
```